# IIS Default document rewrites URL

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, default-document

I configure the default document of site http://www.modapik.com as index.aspx in both IIS and web.config. But when i hit the URL, the browser opens http://www.modapik.com/index.aspx which I totally don' want. How can I configure IIS to open only http://www.modapik.com

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use URL ReWriting feature for this